# Google Chrome Font Issue

Tags: google-chrome, web, webfonts

Which font do I install for these sites?  Obviously it's common, but I can't figure it out.

[image: ThinkGeek.com website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, here are the list of fonts.

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: So if I didn't have those fonts, it would default to, say Arial, which I know I have?

Comment: That is correct. My browser is defaulting to Arial. Helvetica fonts are normally associated with Mac computers.

Comment: Yeah, I finally tried those sites at work, it's obvious I don't have the correct fonts installed on my home computer.